# Проблема с валидациями

Tags: ruby-on-rails, валидация

Не работают валидации
Ошибка:
 `undefined method values_at' for nil:NilClass`
Она вылетает при вводе любой невалидной информации в форме.
Валидатор: `validates :name, presence: true`
html код для вывода ошибок:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@event, url: form_path, html: { class: "form-horizontal" }) do |f| %>
  <% if @event.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <ul>
      <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <fieldset>
```

Ошибка, которую я указал, указывает на первую строку html кода

Comment: Где-то у вас в коде. По приведённым данным дать более точный ответ не представляется возможным.

Comment: @D-side Может так будет яснее?

Comment: Не особенно. Стектрейс есть?

Comment: Application Frames All Frames
#<Class:0x0000000e4d2818>#_app_views_admin_events__form_html_erb__1851837721759590908_58808220
app/views/admin/events/_form.html.erb, line 7
#<Class:0x0000000e4d2818>#_app_views_admin_events_new_html_erb___3782662671648174640_53024120
app/views/admin/events/new.html.erb, line 1
block (2 levels) in Admin::EventsController#create
app/controllers/admin/events_controller.rb, line 124
Admin::EventsController#create
app/controllers/admin/events_controller.rb, line 119 @D-side

Comment: Но в описанных местах, как я понимаю, `values_at` не вызывается, значит вам все фреймы нужны, а не только от приложения. Во всяком случае, от самого верха до места, где первым встречается код приложения. И на этот раз не пытайтесь их упихнуть в комментарий.

Comment: Ну-у? Ждать стектрейс?

Comment: я нашёл проблему, при отправке формы для одного из полей игнорировался ввод пустого значения. Так вот если оставлять его пустым, вылетает данная ошибка @D-side